# -Powershell- How to increment number after file has been deleted

Tags: file, powershell, security, scripting, increment

Creating a script that will compare current groups and users with an original baseline of authorized groups and users. I'm stuck with the file creation. Example of what I want:

---

Original.txt

**If this file somehow was deleted, I want the file to be recreated with the current groups and users

Original2.txt

**If it was deleted again, the same process as above

Original3.txt and so on and so on.

---

Not sure if it's important but here is what i've completed thus far but unable to finish because of the file portion.

```
function not-exist { -not (Test-Path $args) }
Set-Alias !exist not-exist -Option "Constant, AllScope"
Set-Alias exist Test-Path -Option "Constant, AllScope"

#To establish baseline
#Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount > Original.txt
#Get-LocalUser >> .\Original.txt
#Get-LocalGroup >> .\Original.txt

if(exist .\Original.txt) 
{ 
    cd C:\Users\User\Documents
    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount > Compare.txt
    Get-LocalUser >> .\Compare.txt
    Get-LocalGroup >> .\Compare.txt
}

ElseIf (!exist .\Original.txt)
{
    echo "the file has been deleted"
    echo "recreating baseline as 'Original[x]'"

    #I'm stuck on how to recursively create the file here

    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount > Original[x].txt
    Get-LocalUser >> .\Original[x].txt
    Get-LocalGroup >> .\Original[x].txt
}

Else
{
    #????
    echo "the file neither exists or doesn't exist"
}
```

I don't know how simple or complex this is but I hope we can work towards this :)

PS - if there are any additional suggestions, they are welcomed <3

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what you are trying to do here, are you trying to simply create the file if it doesn't exist and append if it does? If you are then you would only need to use Out-File -Append -Force as that will create the file if it doesnt exist anyway

Comment: There is also no reason for the Else, there is no situation whereby the path neither exists and does not exist.

Comment: There is no reason to output the commands to a file. Store it in a variable and process it as a powershell object

Comment: @OwainEsau If the file has been DELETED, then I'll create a different version. This tells me that someone has messed with the original file. So your solution will not help me.

Comment: @KolobCanyon That sounds about right. It's just the first thought that came to mind. At the end, I deleted the file either way but I'll look into making the switch
Thank you both

Comment: @Simonhawk Hmm, you could use a C# file listener? If you're just looking to put an event listener on the file to detect changes?

Comment: This doesn't answer my question but is a different way to solve my solution. I found a link for a listener and I'm going to figure it to satisfy my needs. Thanks! [Link To a Script for a PowerShell File System Watcher](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b)